# ¿Cómo generar las migas de pan (Breadcrumbs) en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Estoy tratando de generar las migas de pan desde mi base de datos, actualmente funciona, pero por problemas de construcción de la miga de pan, existen muchos ID que se repiten, y en algunos no tienen coherencias ya que existe algo como.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, ese **Consolas y videojuegos** no tendría porque estar ahí, tengo el siguiente código

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./BreadCrumbs.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faChevronRight } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

class BreadCrumbs extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="breadcrumbs-wrap">
        <span className="breadcrumbs">ruta</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} className="breadcrumbs" />
        <span className="breadcrumbs">ruta</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} className="breadcrumbs" />
        <span className="breadcrumbs">ruta</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BreadCrumbs;

 // proviene desde la db 

            {mdata.breadcum.map((item, i) => (
                <><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
                  <Link key={i} href="/categoria/[category]" as={"/categoria/" + item.name}>
                    <a>
                      {item.name}
                    </a>
                  </Link></>
            ))}
```

Hasta ahí funciona pero en algunos no se le encuentra la lógica, debido a la cantidad de registros que se deben organizar, podría tardar mucho mas tiempo de lo normal, por lo que ahora es un proceso fundamental para poder iniciar en producción…

Mi pregunta es, de que forma puedo hacer lo mismo pero desde el código, es decir, sin la necesidad de consumir directamente desde la base de datos, sino desde la parte del front

Este es el JSON_ que llena la miga de pan y el detalle del producto

```
{
  asin: 'B07D3NGY3C',
  brand: 'Manhattan',
  breadcum: [
    { category_id: 172282, name: 'Computadoras y accesorios' },
    { category_id: 1292115011, name: 'Monitores' },
    { category_id: 4150, name: 'Computación' }
  ],
  category: {
    banner: ' ',
    category_id: 1292115011,
    created_since: '2021-01-19 15:45:29.145808',
    fullname: 'Computación/Computadoras y accesorios/Monitores',
    in_menu: 0,
    name: 'Monitores',
    parent_id: 172282,
    parent_path: '4150/172282/1292115011',
    status: 1,
    updated_since: '2021-01-19 15:45:29.145808'
  },
  category_id: 1292115011,
  category_tree: '',
  color: 'Negro',
  created_since: '2020-11-18 19:48:48.567498',
  description: 'Administre el escritorio. Maximice la productividad. La instalación de un monitor LCD sobre el escritorio ayuda a maximizar la eficacia de un espacio de trabajo potencial. El soporte para monitor doble universal Manhattan con brazos oscilantes de doble enlace mejora la organización en el escritorio, lo que facilita el trabajo en la computadora.Construido en acero duradero, este soporte para monitor doble cuenta con una base resistente que permite una rápida, fácil y segura Montaje sin necesidad de perforar escritorios o encimeras. Sus configuraciones de inclinación, rotación, de lado a lado, altura y tensión totalmente ajustables crean la posición perfecta para aumentar cómodamente la productividad. Estas capacidades de ajuste pueden incluso ayudar a reducir la fatiga ocular o la tensión del cuello y la espalda. Además, el poste de montaje ofrece una fácil rotación del monitor para permitir que otros vean presentaciones y producciones multimedia desde casi cualquier dirección.',
  discount: '0.00',
  earnings_percentage: '0.28',
  edition: '',
  features: 'Cumple con los estándares VESA: sostiene de forma segura dos monitores LCD de 13 ”a 32” Coloca los monitores sobre el escritorio para aumentar el trabajo espacio, mejore la visibilidad y minimice el desorden Brazos oscilantes de doble enlace con inclinación separada de 45 °, rotación de 180 ° y ajustes de altura variable Poste de acero con soporte de escritorio para trabajo pesado - Placas VESA extraíbles, lo que agiliza y facilita la instalación del monitor Garantía de por vida Cuando se compra al fabricante o se autoriza revendedor',
  format: '',
  genre: 'None',
  height: '18.30705',
  images: [
    {
      created_since: '2020-12-31 08:00:34.293752',
      file_id: 1017750045,
      main: 1,
      product_id: 46796690,
      status: 1,
      updated_since: null,
      url: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417GaI+Uu8L.jpg'
    },
    {
      created_since: '2020-12-31 08:00:34.293752',
      file_id: 1032010360,
      main: 0,
      product_id: 46796690,
      status: 1,
      updated_since: null,
      url: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lydO4kkLL.jpg'
    },
    {
      created_since: '2020-12-31 08:00:34.293752',
      file_id: 1063653254,
      main: 0,
      product_id: 46796690,
      status: 1,
      updated_since: null,
      url: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/312Tlus1+kL.jpg'
    },
    {
      created_since: '2020-12-31 08:00:34.293752',
      file_id: 1083116774,
      main: 0,
      product_id: 46796690,
      status: 1,
      updated_since: null,
      url: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41D3D01nrDL.jpg'
    }
  ],
  information: 'Cumple con los estándares VESA: sostiene de forma segura dos monitores LCD de 13 ”a 32” Coloca los monitores sobre el escritorio para aumentar el trabajo espacio, mejore la visibilidad y minimice el desorden Brazos oscilantes de doble enlace con inclinación separada de 45 °, rotación de 180 ° y ajustes de altura variable Poste de acero con soporte de escritorio para trabajo pesado - Placas VESA extraíbles, lo que agiliza y facilita la instalación del monitor Garantía de por vida Cuando se compra al fabricante o se autoriza revendedor',
  is_adult_product: 0,
  is_prime: 1,
  length: '1.4960600000000002',
  model: '461559',
  package_height: '4.13385',
  package_length: '19.2913',
  package_quantity: '-1',
  package_weight: '10.9349281952',
  package_width: '11.57478',
  platform: '',
  price: '503331.92',
  product_group: 'Personal Computer',
  product_id: 46796690,
  size: '',
  sku: '',
  status: 1,
  stock: 5,
  store_id: null,
  title: ' soporte universal para dos monitores con brazos oscilantes de doble enlace Sostiene dos monitores LCD de 13 "a 32" de hasta 8 kg (17 Lbs.), Negro',
  type: 'MONITOR',
  updated_since: '2020-12-30 00:00:00',
  usd: '$ 89,00',
  user: { last_name: '', name: 'SpiceStock', photo: null, user_id: 16 },
  user_id: 16,
  weight: '9.900960186419999',
  width: '31.417260000000002'
}
```

Comment: No existe una categorización desde la BD? Porque si al consultar la BD te trae todo eso sin ningún tipo de ID que te ayude a segmentar los items, tendrías que hacerlo tú mismo en el código mediante JSON

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, si existe una categorizacion y tambien los ID padres, hijos y nietos incluso hasta los niveles... pero por temas de organizacion, es decir el personal encargado de hacerlo... incluyo ID dentro de rutas que no deberian ir, como el ejemplo de video juegos salen en otra categoria, por temas tiempo no se puede corregir en detalle, por eso busco una solucion alternativa

Comment: Ufff esos organizadores... ¿? ... podrías incluir el JSON con el que llenas los breadcrumbs? Así tenemos una mejor visualización del problema

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, dame un momento ya lo comparto

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Buen dia, edite la pregunte y le anexe el JSON

Comment: Habría opción que incluyas el JSON que arma el ejemplo de los videojuegos y los hornos? Porque el que me enviaste esta correcto

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, el que te envie esta correcto, es con el fin de mostrar como se genera, el de videojuegos y hornos, evidentemente es un problema con la relacion de los ID de las categorias es decir, en la miga de pan incluyeron dentro de la catgegoria hornos, un ID de video juegos, el problema es ese.... lo que yo estoy tratando de generar aunque no se si se 'pueda es eso mismo solo que no provenga de la base de datos sino del mismo codigo, es decir como lo muestra bootstrap por ejemplo

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera algo así mas o menos https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/breadcrumb/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118711/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-soft-quick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el mismo `JSON` tiene un campo que te sirve para listar correctamente el elemento, que es **fullname**. Entonces, simplemente debes construir el `breadcrumb` referenciando a esta propiedad y *no al arreglo breadcum*.

```
<Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrum">
   <Typography color="inherit">{data.category.fullname}</Typography>
</Breadcrumbs>
```

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-krtlb?file=/src/App.js)** te dejo el ejemplo completo para que lo analices.

> PD: El código que está comentado, sirve para destacar el último
> elemento del Breadcrumb de otro color, si quieres lo descomentas y
> visualizas cuál te sirve más.
>
> PD.2: El componente está construido utilizando **[Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/)**

Saludos!

Comment: Esta perfecto, gracias